# Find unique value for each category

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a two columns:

```
category     names
vegetables   [broccoli, ginger]
fruit        [apple, grapes, dragonfruit]
vegetables   [pine]
vegetables   [bottleguord, pumpkin]
fruit        [mango, guava]
```

I need to find unique values that each category contains.
This is how you could create a new df

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame({'category':['vegetables', 'fruit', 'vegetables', 'vegetables', 'fruit'],
                       'Names':['[broccoli, ginger]','[apple, grapes, dragonfruit]','[pine]','[bottleguord, pumpkin]', '[mango, guava]']})
```

This is how I was trying to do it.

```
g = df.groupby('category')['names'].apply(lambda x: list(np.unique(x)))
```

Expected output:

```
index = ['Vegetables' ,'Fruits']
new_df = pd.DataFrame(index=index)
```

This is how I tweaked the code: `print(df.assign(Names=df['Names'].str[1:-1].str.split(', ')).explode('Names').groupby('Category')['Names'].apply(lambda x: len(set(x))))`

```
catgeory    len_unique_val
Vegetables   5
Fruits       4
```

Comment: please share expected output format.

Comment: @Abdul I added the expected output. I am facing a keyword error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `explode`, `groupby` and `apply` to transform as python set.

##### assuming lists as input:

```
(df.explode('names')
   .groupby('category')
   ['names']
   .apply(set)
)
```

output:

```
category
fruit             {dragonfruit, guava, grapes, apple, mango}
vegetables    {ginger, pine, broccoli, bottleguord, pumpkin}
```

##### assuming strings as input:

```
(df.assign(Names=df['Names'].str[1:-1].str.split(', '))
   .explode('Names')
   .groupby('category')
   ['Names']
   .apply(lambda x: '['+', '.join(set(x))+']')
)
```

output:

```
category
fruit             [dragonfruit, guava, grapes, apple, mango]
vegetables    [ginger, pine, broccoli, bottleguord, pumpkin]
```

Comment: @chixy I see your input was likely strings, I updated the answer